# I need my children container to take equal space without specifying the container width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Expanded(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        color: Colors.red,
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the container inside a expanded widget to the desired

`Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),`